# How to format a 14-digit number (in a csvfile) into Ymd in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which one column is the date. It's written like 20130314151615
how can i manipulate the whole column so that i get the year, month and day?

20130314151615 to 2013-03-14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `lubridate` package we can make use of `as_date` after defining `ymd_hms`:

```
library(lubridate)
as_date(ymd_hms(20130314151615))
```

```
[1] "2013-03-14"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you wanted

```
as.Date( "20130314151615", format="%Y%m%d" )
[1] "2013-03-14"
```